# How do I write this `method_missing`?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a class `Wrapper` that supports adding options that you can then look up later. It stores these options in an internal hash `@dict`.

```
w = Wrapper.new
w.foo # => NameError
w.foo = 10
w.foo # => 10
```

How can I write a `method_missing` for `Wrapper` so that I can support nested calls on `@dict`?

```
w = Wrapper.new
w.foo.bar.baz = 1000
w.foo.bar.baz # => 1000
```

Answer (score 5):

If this isn't what you are looking for, leave a comment.

```
class Wrapper
  def initialize(d={})
    @dict = d
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    if method.to_s =~ /=$/
      @dict[method.to_s.match(/^(.*)=$/)[1].to_sym] = args.first
    else
      @dict[method] ||= Wrapper.new
    end
  end
end

w = Wrapper.new
w.foo = 5
w.foo #=> 5
w.x.y.z = 32
w.x.y.w = 43
w.x.y.z #=> 32
w.x.y.w #=> 43
```

Comment: Does this support OP's chaining request?

Comment: @Jeriko - Look at the lines at the end. Yes.